# Assigning length of a list in the parameters of a function

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments

So I would like to set the length of a list to a variable in my function, but it says my list is not defined:

```
def maxElement(list, start=0, end = len(serie)):
    return max(serie[start:end])

serie = [9, 3, 6, 1, 7, 5, 4, 8, 2]
print maxElement(serie)
```

Comment: Calling the `len` function in the signature of `maxElement` will fail, because `serie` is not yet defined. But the better questions is, why would you want to do that? Your list is being passed as a parameter, so call `len(list)` inside your function to know its length.

Comment: BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name as that shadows the built-in `list` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

Firstly, you don't actually use the `list` argument of the function. Instead, you are using the global list `serie`. BTW, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name as that shadows (overwrites) the built-in `list` type, which can lead to mysterious bugs.

As schwobaseggl mentions, default function parameters are evaluated when the function is defined, not when it's called. So when you do `end = len(serie)` that sets `end` to the current length of `serie` at the time the function is defined. However, your script defines `serie` after it defines `maxElement`, so that name hasn't been defined yet, which is why you get this error:

```
NameError: name 'serie' is not defined
```

If you put the definition for `serie` *before* the definition of `maxElement` that will get rid of that error, but the function still won't work correctly because of the errors I already mentioned.

Actually, there *could* be another error. It *looks* like you want to search for the maximum element between `start` and `end`, inclusively. If so you need to use something like `lst[start:end+1]`. If you want to go with the normal Python convention where `end` is excluded from the range, then you can just use `lst[start:end]`. Note that it doesn't matter if the end index of a slice goes beyond the list; for `n` > 0, `lst[start:len(lst)+n]` is exactly the same slice as `lst[start:len(lst)]`.

Here's a repaired version of your code. I've modified the data slightly to make it easier to test.

```
def max_element(lst, start=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end = len(lst)
    return max(lst[start:end + 1])

serie = [0, 3, 6, 1, 7, 5, 4, 8, 2]

print serie
print max_element(serie)
print max_element(serie, start=4)
print max_element(serie, end=2)
print max_element(serie, start=4, end=6)
print max_element(serie, start=3, end=3)
```

**output**

```
[0, 3, 6, 1, 7, 5, 4, 8, 2]
8
8
6
7
1
```

**However**, this function isn't really necessary. You should just call `max` directly on your list, sliced if necessary, eg:

```
print max(serie[4:7])
```

Comment: Pretty comprehensive explanation! But why use `end + 1` in the slice instead of just `end`? **Update:** After all, the last list index is `len(lst)-1` anyway..

Answer (score 3):

At the time of your function definition, `serie` is not yet defined. Also, default parameters are evaluated and bound at module loading time, not when the the function is called. So, you CANNOT refer to another argument either a la `maxElement(lst, start=0, end=len(lst))` or have any other dynamic runtime-dependent defaults:

```
def maxElement(lst, start=0, end=None):  # don't shadow built-in name list
    if end is None:
        end = len(lst)
    return max(lst[start:end])  # do not use serie here, but lst

> serie = [9, 3, 6, 1, 7, 5, 4, 8, 2]
> print maxElement(serie)
9

> print maxElement(serie, start=1, end=6)
7
```